# Unable to create Regex for JSON value

Tags: java, json, regex, serenity

I have `JSON` for which I sometimes got some alphanumeric name in one key value name and sometimes it is `null` like below.

```
{"name":"77Watcher"}
{"name":null}
```

I have to validate the data I am using like below.

```
{"name":"${json-unit.matches:^([A-Za-z0-9]+|null)$}"}
```

But getting `Matcher "^([A-Za-z0-9]+|null)$"` not found.

If I use `{"name":"${json-unit.matches:[A-z0-9]|null"}` then getting `<"${json-unit.matches:[A-z0-9]|null"> but was: <null>`.

Is there any proper regex that I can put into my code for that?

Comment: If I am reading your notation correctly it looks like you regex is trying to match the word null within double quotes.  But in the actual JSON there are no double quotes around the word null.

Comment: yes, so how can I deal with that @Malcolm? 
Thanks :)

Comment: Does `^(\"[A-Za-z0-9]+\"|null)$` work for you? Check [demo](https://regex101.com/r/XMisgV/1).

Comment: if i write like <"${json-unit.matches:^(\\\"[A-Za-z0-9]+\\\"|null)$"> but was: <null> same error

Comment: Can you provide some context, possibly the routine you're running.  Is this part of an _annotation_?

Answer (score 0):

The way it's written, isn't it looking for *"null"* instead of *null*? So by putting the double quotes with the character grouping instead of around both the character grouping and the null, it should match.

Comment: You've got some, uh, interesting notations in there - your use of $ and ^ in particular don't appear to follow the usual meaning. But you still had an additional double quote in addition to the other weirdness. Try: <"${json-unit.matches:^(\\\"[A-Za-z0-9]+\\\"|null)$>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I must say I am unfamiliar with the exact notation you are using.  You appear to be using some parser that has the embedded regex matching in it, rather than having a regex that matches the entire JSON string. It would appear that everything outside of your dollar-braced unit is being interpreted literally in which case you need to not have the double quotes when you are matching the null expression.  So, depending upon how your parser handles the embedded quotes in the regex, you either want

```
{"name":${json-unit.matches:^(\"[A-Za-z0-9]+\"|null)$}}
```

or

```
{"name":${json-unit.matches:^(\\\"[A-Za-z0-9]+\\\"|null)$}}
```